# shell script to remove selected directories

Tags: shell

i have bunch of dirs , say **a, b, c0, d, Z , foo, ** and so on.

I want to  remove all the directories except dirs **foo, foo2, a** and **b**

can anyone provide me the syntax to do this shell?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I just want to say Thank you to all of you for your responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way;

```
mkdir ../tempdir
mv foo foo2 a b ../tempdir
rm *
mv ../tempdir/* .
rmdir ../tempdir
```

Please note that this deletes also all **files**, not just directories.

Comment: ah! That's it! In fact I also want to delete files. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

```
echo `ls -1 -d */ | egrep -v '^(foo|foo2|a|b)/$'`
```

If you are satisfied with the output, replace `echo` with `rmdir` (or `rm -r`, if the directories still contain data).

Comment: Put up the `$()` or backtick escaped example as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` on a complicated command line, but perhaps the simplest and, more importantly, safest way is to create a file that lists all of the directories you want to remove.  Then use the file as input to `rm` like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d > dirs_to_remove
```

Now edit the file and take out any directories you want to *keep*, then use `rm`:

```
rm -ir $(<edited_dirs_to_remove)
```

Note the `-i` argument.  It's optional and forces `rm` to ask you before deleting each file.
Also note the `$(<filename)` syntax, which is specific to bash and is equivalent to, but cheaper than `$(cat filename)`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more powerful ways to do this sort of trick is using find + grep + xargs:

```
DONT_REMOVE='a|b|c0|d|Z|foo'
find . -type d -print | egrep -v "^\.$DONT_REMOVE\$" | xargs rm -r
```

The only trick here is making sure the pattern matches only those you don't want to remove.
The above pattern only matches files in the current directory.  You can make it more or less
permissive, e.g:

```
IF_PATH_IS_IMMEDIATE_SUBDIR="^\./($DONT_REMOVE)$"
IF_PATH_ENDS_IN="/($DONT_REMOVE)$"
IF_PATH_CONTAINS="/($DONT_REMOVE)(/.*)?$"
```

Then pass one of these in your egrep, e.g:

```
find . -type d -print | egrep -v "$IF_PATH_ENDS_IN" | xargs rm -r
```

To invert the choice (ie. delete all those items) just remove the -v from the egrep

Comment: You can simplify this by adding "-maxdepth 1" to the find command.  "Find" is a lot like "make" -- I'm never done learning it.  :-)

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure if one level of subdirs was all that was needed, hence the different options.

Comment: `find` (at least the GNU version) has `-regex` so you could eliminate `egrep`. Also, if you do `find ... -print0 | egrep -z ... | xargs -0 ...` your command will work with files that have spaces in their names.

Answer (score 0):

one way

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name "bar" -a ! -name "foo" -a ! -name "a" -a ! -name "b" \) -delete  # to remove files as well, remove -type d
```

OR try using extglob

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -rf !(foo|bar|a|b)/  # to delete files as well, remove the last "/"
```

And yes, this assume you don't want the rest of the directories in your directory except the 4 directories you want.

Comment: !!! WARNING !!! This assumes there are no subdirectories under a, b, bar, and foo.  The names of the subdirectories do NOT match the criteria, and they will be deleted.

Comment: Moral:  NEVER execute a bulk delete command unless you've verified that it will do what you expect.  In the case of find, simply remove the -delete command.  In general, test the command by replacing "rm" with "ls"